# Modifying Dynamic Text with Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

At the moment I'm working on a project that involves increasing/decreasing the alpha and scale of text within a flash movie (at the moment it randomly chooses between several groups of symbols, increases the alpha for the chosen symbol, and then scales the symbol out while decreasing the alpha). Each bit of text to be modified is its own symbol occupying a separate layer of the movie. And, for the initial project it's serving quite well, but I'd like to be able to reuse the code for similar projects in the future without having to create new symbols to be modified.

I'd like to find a way to create a single source for text objects to be modified (like a text array that can be modified/displayed), but I haven't been able to find one thus far. What I've found about Text fields seem promising, but I can't find anything about being able to modify the alpha or scale values of them. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or at least tell me if text fields would be appropriate for the use I'd like to put them?

Comment: Do you mean dynamically modifying a single text field? If so, it's as simple as `myTextField.alpha = 0.5;` or `myTextField.scaleX = 1.5;` to modify it in real time.

Comment: Do you intend to animate each lettre of a text independently?

Comment: @Kodiak No, I don't intend to modify each letter separately. Only as whole words/phrases

Comment: @Sim The goal for this would be to start with a single source for the text, like a String array, and display/modify the contents on the stage when appropriate during the video.